# How ADF Dataflow will read columns and rows from separate arrays and generate csv file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Below is my API response, where I get columns details an row details in separate array.

```
[    
    {
        "FrameType": "DataTable",
        "TableId": 1,
        "TableKind": "PrimaryResult",
        "TableName": "PrimaryResult",
        "Columns": [
            {
                "ColumnName": "RecordID",
                "ColumnType": "string"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "RecordNumber",
                "ColumnType": "integer"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "IsValid",
                "ColumnType": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "Remarks",
                "ColumnType": "string"
            }
        ],
        "Rows": [
            [
                "record1",
                123,
                true,
                "test1"
            ],
            [
                "record2",
                456,
                false,
                "test2"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, using Azure Data Factory, I would like to generate a csv into blob based on above response.

I have tried a data flow with derived columns and some flatten transformations. But I am not soo successful in this attempt. Below is the JSON for my dataflow.

```
{
    "name": "df_ADX_REST_TagsInfo",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "ls_ADX_REST_API",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "ADXRestApi"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "linkservice_cloudshellstorageforbh",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "WriteColumnstoCSV"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "FilterAPIResponse"
                },
                {
                    "name": "flatten1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     access_token as string",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          body as (Cancelled as boolean, Columns as (ColumnName as string, ColumnType as string)[], FrameType as string, HasErrors as boolean, IsProgressive as boolean, Rows as string[][], TableId as short, TableKind as string, TableName as string, Version as string),",
                "          headers as [string,string]",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     format: 'rest',",
                "     timeout: 30,",
                "     requestInterval: 0,",
                "     entity: '/v2/rest/query',",
                "     headers: ['Content-Type' -> 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization' -> ($access_token), 'Accept' -> 'application/json', 'Host' -> 'help.kusto.windows.net'],",
                "     httpMethod: 'POST',",
                "     body: ('{\"db\":\"bhTestDB\",  \"csl\":\"TagsInfo | summarize arg_max(ingestion_time(),*) by TimeseriesId\"}'),",
                "     paginationRules: ['supportRFC5988' -> 'true'],",
                "     responseFormat: ['type' -> 'json', 'documentForm' -> 'documentPerLine']) ~> ADXRestApi",
                "ADXRestApi filter(body.TableKind=='PrimaryResult') ~> FilterAPIResponse",
                "FilterAPIResponse foldDown(unroll(body.Columns),",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          Columns = body.Columns.ColumnName",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: false) ~> flatten1",
                "FilterAPIResponse derive(Tags = toString(unfold(split(toString(body.Rows), '],[')))) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 derive(Tags = replace(replace(Tags,'[[',''),']]','')) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn2 select(mapColumn(",
                "          Tags",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "flatten1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     input(",
                "          {{} as string",
                "     ),",
                "     format: 'delimited',",
                "     container: 'data',",
                "     columnDelimiter: ',',",
                "     escapeChar: '\\\\',",
                "     quoteChar: '\\\"',",
                "     columnNamesAsHeader: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> WriteColumnstoCSV"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone here suggest me an approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the above transformations, you get the data as shown in the below image.

[image]

- This file has 4 columns with 2 rows but no header. To integrate this with columns names, you can use the following. Extract the `ColumnNames` after `flatten` transformation to get data like in the below image:

[image]

- Now write this to a sink CSV file with the dataset configurations as shown in the below image:

[image]

- This would give a file data as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Now I have 2 files, `rows.csv and cols.csv`. Using the following dataflow, I was able to get the complete csv file.

```
{
    "name": "dataflow2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "s2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                },
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "s3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source2"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "d1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          RecordID as string,",
                "          RecordNumber as string,",
                "          IsValid as string,",
                "          Remarks as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source(output(",
                "          Column_1 as string,",
                "          Column_2 as string,",
                "          Column_3 as string,",
                "          Column_4 as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source2",
                "source1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          RecordID,",
                "          RecordNumber,",
                "          IsValid,",
                "          Remarks",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1, source2 union(byName: false)~> union1",
                "union1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['final.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]